# UInt throwing OverflowException

Tags: c#

On entering negative values to a textbox I get an error saying `Unhandled Exception: System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32.`

Here is my code :

```
 UInt32 n = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox2.Text);    
         if (n > 0)
          //code 
         else
         //code
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect? `uint` can't represent negative numbers(It's unsigned), so throwing an exception, instead of returning nonsensical data is a good choice. You probably want `uint.TryParse`, but your question is a bit underspecified.

Comment: Why not use the built in `int` alias?

Comment: I would suggest reading a good book on basics of programming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because `UInt32` is unsigned. You should use `Int32` (which is unsigned) instead.

So your code should look like:

```
Int32 n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
if (n > 0)
  //code 
else
  //code
```

However, I would rather put it like that:

```
int n;
// TryParse method tries parsing and returns true on successful parsing
if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out n))
{
    if (n > 0)
         // code for positive n
    else
         // code for negative n
}
else
     // handle parsing error
```

Comment: Ah ! I was mixing Uint and Int ,but clear enough now . But why would you write your code like that ? Calling a function is a bit expensive  ! No ?

Comment: @kushal well, not _that_ expensive, I think. Or even not expensive at all. However, I call a parsing function one time, and you do the same, so there are no extra calls.

Comment: @kushal the reason I wrote the code like that is control: I control whether the value was parsed or not and then can decide if I should throw and exception or just show a message to the user. If I got your question wrong, please tell me so I could answer the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Entering a negative value means you are trying to convert a negative signed value, into an unsigned value which results in an over flow exception. Either use Int32 or check for negative numbers and do something to prevent the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a negative value to an unsigned value. [The MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1a7zd61.aspx) specifically states you will get an exception. Instead do the following:

```
Int32 n= Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
UInt32 m = (UInt32) n;
```

Comment: Simply store the value in an Int32, then use a cast. UInt32 unsignedValue = (UInt32) signedValue;

Comment: I got the answer so i deleted comment but your solution will not work. It doesn't retrieve the same value of signed integer. You should check by yourself first

Comment: It does work for values that fit into a signed integer. Obviously, negative values are cast as positive values so it shifts everything.